# Shorter version of switch statement for complex cases

Tags: javascript

It is possible to make shorter version of this statement? I know that there is shorthand for switch statement if cases are like 1,2,3 etc.

```
    var direction = pos[i].direction;
    switch (true) {
        case (direction >= 0 && direction < 22):
            graphic = "/img/0.png"
            break;
        case (direction >= 22 && direction < 45):
            graphic = "/img/225.png"
            break;
        case (direction >= 45 && direction < 67):
            graphic = "/img/450.png"
            break;
        case (direction >= 67 && direction < 90):
            graphic = "/img/675.png"
            break;
        default:
            graphic = "/img/0.png"
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could omit the first check, because the value is already checked before.

```
switch (true) {
    case direction < 22:
        graphic = "/img/0.png";
        break;
    case direction < 45:
        graphic = "/img/225.png";
        break;
    case direction < 67:
        graphic = "/img/450.png";
        break;
    case direction < 90:
        graphic = "/img/675.png";
        break;
    default:
        graphic = "/img/0.png";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Hi, you can also omit first case as it is in default.

Comment: no, then you need a check for greater or equal than `22` additionally for smaller than `45`.

Comment: it looks, that `graphic = "/img/0.png"` is the default value either at values smaller than `22` or greater/equal than `90`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use if else because you have conditions ready with you.so no need to use switch case.